# How should I paint over a large patched area on a wall?

Tags: walls, painting, patch

I have a wall with a approx 20 by 20 cm patched wall. Quite large. I primed the patch then painted over the entire wall (with the patch) 3 times and the patch is still visible. What can I do next that will make the match less visible? (Besides placing a large furniture in front of it).

Comment: At this point, not much except for doing it over, covering it up with furniture or a picture, or just living with it. You'll forget all about it soon, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to completely eliminate signs of a patch. Try to get the patch as level with the rest of the wall for starters. You're still going to have some irregularities from the mud but if you feather it out it's less noticeable.

Just mud the outside of the patch for now. Do multiple light coats until you get out to a 12" taping knife. That should leave a gradual slope that will be less noticeable.

After the outside dries scrape down the inside edges a bit to get them a little even then  do two or 3 coats to fill in the inside of the patch so that the inside is flush with the inner rim from the outside mud.

Use a straightedge and a work light on the side of the wall to check for irregularities.

Once you're happy with it, prime then paint. Using a paint with very little sheen will help to hide any imperfections too.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all it would be really helpful if we could see the picture. But from what I heard there are two possible scenarios: the patch is flat with the rest of the wall. In this case you should apply 2,3 or maybe even more layers of smoothing primer, and then sand it off with extra fine sand paper; also you can apply last layer or two on the surrounding areas. If you are afraid that smoothing primer might crack, which is really possible when this thick you can apply product similar to knauf's fugenfuller (original name is in German language) which doesn’t crack. Then you just pain it over. If patch is not flat the best would be to try to flatten the plaster on the patch with the rest of the wall (imp guessing its plaster), if that is not possible I’m not sure that you can make it invisible (since I’m professional I’m sure I would spot it, since it’s my job :) ) maybe you should thing about making it different. The rest of the wall can be let’s say white, but this patch could be...red.Idea is that the color of the patch is dramatically different than the color of the rest of the wall.